# openstack Quantum VM able to ping br-ex but not outside network

Tags: linux, openstack, bridge

I have a very strange issue related to my network, I have installed RDO Grizzly OpenStack on VirtualBox with multiple interfaces.

VirtualBox:

```
eth0 - management (Host-only - 172.16.100.1/24)
eth1 - Outside connectivity floating IP (Host-only - 192.168.200.1/24)
```

Within the OS I have configured the following IP address:

```
eth0 - 172.16.100.3/24
eth1 - NO IP  (bridge configuration br-ex) 

br-ex - 192.168.200.10/24
```

VM configuration:

```
eth0 - 10.0.0.1
```

### Problem:

From within the VM I am able to ping `192.168.200.10` but not `192.168.200.1` (which I configured in Host-only VirtualBox interface).

If I run `tcpdump` on br-ex I getting `ARP request` only:

```
[root@openstack ~]# tcpdump -i br-ex -n
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on br-ex, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
09:57:38.409836 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.200.1 tell 192.168.200.3, length 28
09:57:39.409347 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.200.1 tell 192.168.200.3, length 28
09:57:40.409269 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.200.1 tell 192.168.200.3, length 28
09:57:42.301261 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.200.1 tell 192.168.200.3, length 28
```

But from the `nova compute` node I can SSH VM using floating IP.

```
[root@openstack ~]# ovs-vsctl show
87c47768-6915-4a22-89ce-07ae6a69198c
    Bridge br-int
        Port "tap22f39fba-90"
            tag: 1
            Interface "tap22f39fba-90"
        Port br-int
            Interface br-int
                type: internal
        Port "qvo04567a2c-21"
            tag: 1
            Interface "qvo04567a2c-21"
        Port "tapf883d479-d3"
            tag: 1
            Interface "tapf883d479-d3"
    Bridge br-ex
        Port "tapefe0165b-fd"
            Interface "tapefe0165b-fd"
        Port br-ex
            Interface br-ex
                type: internal
        Port "eth1"
            Interface "eth1"
    ovs_version: "1.11.0"
```

`ip link` command output:

```
[root@openstack ~]# ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:76:b9:0e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:3e:9f:a5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:41:a1:b9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: ovs-system: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN
    link/ether 56:3e:40:7c:48:01 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: br-ex: <BROADCAST,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
    link/ether 08:00:27:3e:9f:a5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
7: br-int: <BROADCAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
    link/ether 7a:0f:17:14:72:44 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
11: tapf883d479-d3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether a6:1e:ad:c4:e4:1a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
12: qbr04567a2c-21: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
    link/ether 3e:a1:d0:98:7c:f8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
13: qvo04567a2c-21: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 26:8f:28:d2:ca:cd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
14: qvb04567a2c-21: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 3e:a1:d0:98:7c:f8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
16: tapefe0165b-fd: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether f2:fa:3e:b9:e6:62 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
19: tap22f39fba-90: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 4e:27:93:05:5a:bb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
20: tap04567a2c-21: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN qlen 500
    link/ether fe:16:3e:e8:6a:4e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

`ip route` command output:

```
[root@openstack ~]# ip route
192.168.200.0/24 dev br-ex  scope link
192.168.200.0/24 dev eth1  scope link
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  scope link  metric 1002
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth1  scope link  metric 1003
172.16.0.0/16 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.16.100.3
default via 172.16.100.1 dev eth0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its wired but problem solved!

Configured eth1 with following options:

```
DEVICE=eth1
ONBOOT=yes
HWADDR=08:00:27:3E:9F:A5
TYPE=OVSPort
DEVICETYPE=ov
OVS_BRIDGE=br-ex
NM_CONTROLLED=no
IPV6INIT=no
```

Reboot this box

after reboot

manually set ip on `br-ex`

```
ip addr add 192.168.200.10/24 dev br-ex
```